# Sequelize mysql order by concat of two fields

Tags: express, sequelize.js

My DB has a users table that has a `first_name`,`last_name` columns, either of them maybe empty.

I also have a UI dashboard that displays a table with a `full_name` column that is a concatenation of the two fields, this column is sortable.

I am using sequelize with a mysql database to fetch the users, how can I order by `full_name` (And trim the spaces of the concatenated field)

Comment: You can use virtual fields for getting `full_name`, but you can not order by `full_name` as it doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Thats exactly my issue, i need to order by both columns

Comment: For query optimization purpose it is better to create another column with full_name (or can be a virtual column), you can populate full_name column for existing data with the help of query and while adding new entries you can concatenate first_name and last_name and insert the result

Answer (score 0):

**The SQL solution**

You can order by multiple columns

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC
```

OR you first concatenate the two fields and order by `full_name` (but keep in mind this might be slow)

```
SELECT *, TRIM(CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name)) full_name FROM user ORDER BY full_name ASC
```

**The Sequelize solution**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100)
    },
    last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100)
    },
    //virtual attribute for concatenation of first_name and last_name
    full_name: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get() {
            const firstName = this.getDataValue('first_name');
            const lastName = this.getDataValue('last_name');
            return [firstName, lastName].join(' ').trim();
        }
    },
});

User.findAll({
    /** Order by multiples columns **/
    //order: [['first_name', 'DESC'], ['last_name', 'ASC']],
    /** Order by the two fields concatenated and trimed */
    order: Sequelize.literal("trim(concat(first_name,' ', last_name)) ASC")
}).then(users => {
    users.forEach(user=> {
        console.log(user.get());
    })
})
```